# Запустить php как html

Tags: php

Переименовал index.php в index.html  и не могу запустить, как сделать чтоб php код выполнялся с разрешением html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас apache.
Создайте или измените файл .htaccess в директории с проектом. Нужно добавить строку

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
```

Answer (score 4):

Для этого необходимо настроить ваш веб сервер, подозреваю используете Apache2:

Добавьте строки в .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

для php5:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

или

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Не забудьте перезапустить сервер.

Comment: AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html   в httpd.conf добавил